# Can I use a 3-wire AC adapter in a DC circuit?

Tags: adapter, ac-dc

I am reading through the excellent book *Make Electronics* and am in a chapter that suggests getting an AC adapter, cutting off the connector at the end and stripping the rubber outer coating back to expose the *two* conductors inside. When I did this with an AC adapter that I had laying around in the house, I found three wires inside instead of two. One was black, another red and the third yellow.

[image]

After googling a bit, I am guessing that the black is negative, the red positive and yellow neutral? I could be wrong, though. But, can I use this 3-wire setup to feed DC power into my circuit? And if so, do I use all three wires?

Comment: Also questioning whether this is an AC-DC adapter? It only says that it is a "power supply".

Comment: Whatever you do, DO NOT PLUG THIS IN until you are absolutely sure what it is!

Comment: AC adapters usually have a label or writing on them that specifies what their output is. Perhaps you could edit your question to include that and/or a URL to a photo on a public website.

Comment: A picture of the device, the wire, and the labelling is necessary to answer this question.

Comment: ************  DANGER *********** / Warning. That colour code is "almost" standard for the mains INPUT side of an adaptor. (Yellow is green/yellow striped (or just green) = ground. Red = phase, black = neutral). The manufacturer MAY have used mains-like colour codes, but ensure you have the correct "side" of the adaptor.

Comment: Here is a photo of it, if that helps! (http://i.imgur.com/nNOgCR0.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

Read the label on the power supply and it should be no surprise there are three wires.  Note that this supply doesn't put out a single voltage, which would require two wires.  The label clearly shows that this supply puts out 5 V and 12 V, hence it needs at least three wires.  Usually when a supply puts out multiple voltages, they have a common ground, which is also the case here.  That is why there are only three wires instead of four.

Black is almost certainly the common ground.  Use a meter to see which one is 5 V and which one is 12 V.

Comment: This turned out to be right! Measuring voltage, black was common ground, yellow was 5V and red was 12v.

Answer (score 2):

Black is most likely common ground, red might be 12V DC and yellow may be 5V DC - but that is guesswork. Red and yellow might be the other way around.

Use a multimeter to check voltage from black to red and from black to yellow.

It sound like you'll only need black and one of the others - depending on what voltage suits the circuit you want to provide power to.

Comment: Thanks! Spot on. Black turned out to be ground. Yellow measured 5v and red 12v.

Answer (score 1):

The power supply showing is an ac/dc adapter. It is intended to run a dc device with the separate voltage levels. You can tell it runs dc by the lines next to the amount of output written on the lable. There is a broken line and a solid one underneath.  That is the symbol for direct current.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, that RED & Black usually denote Positive & Negative.

If the end you cut off has only two connections then the third wire must have been tied to either the RED or BLACK at the "load" end of the chord. This is a configuration sometimes used to compensate for voltage drop in the chord by measuring the voltage as near to the load as possible and sending that measurement back to the regulator in the power "Brick".

If you still have the cutoff end, you could measure the resistance between the different wires in hopes of getting a clue, or if that is unrevealing - try disassembling the cutoff end for some physical evidence as to the connection.

Do not connect this to your project until you are sure of the proper arrangement.